# Map One-To-One Relationship Doesn't Allow Inserting

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-one

I'm trying to setup a one-to-one mapping from my Users to the UserDetails table.  Say I have the following tables in my database:

```
Users:

- UserID (PK, Identity)
- UserName
- Password

UsersDetails:

- UserID (PK, FK)
- FirstName
- LastName
```

I have created the following poco classes:

```
public class User {
    public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual UserDetails Details { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetails {
    public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    public UserDetails() {
    }

    public UserDetails(User user) {
        User = user;
    }
}
```

Which are fluently mapped (please note the xml mapping is very similar and if all you know is the xml mapping then I would still appreciate you guidance):

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User> {
    public UserMap() {
        Table("Users");
        Id(x => x.UserID);
        Map(x => x.UserName);
        Map(x => x.Password);
        HasOne(x => x.Details)
            .Constrained()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class UserDetailsMap : ClassMap<UserDetails> {
    public UserDetailsMap() {
        Table("UsersDetails");
        Id(x => x.UserID)
            .GeneratedBy.Foreign("User");
        HasOne(x => x.User)
            .Constrained();
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
    }
}
```

Everything displays correctly but if I say:

```
var user = new User() { UserName = "Test", Password = "Test" };
user.Details = new UserDetails(user) { FirstName = "Test", LastName = "Test" };
session.Save(user);
```

I get the error:

"NHibernate.Id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for: UserDetails."

I'd really appreciate it if someone could show me what I've done wrong.  Thanks

**Edit:** Courtesy of Jamie Ide's suggestion.  I have changed my User mapping to:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User> {
    public UserMap() {
        Table("Users");
        Id(x => x.UserID);
        Map(x => x.UserName);
        Map(x => x.Password);
        References(x => x.Details, "UserID")
            .Class<UserDetails>()
            .Unique();
    }
}
```

But now when i insert a user i get the error:

"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

If i add Cascade.All() on to my Reference i receive the original error i was getting about the null id generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research it appears that this won't work in version 2.0. I am now in a position to upgrade to version 3.0 where i believe this is now possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think `Constrained` should only be specified in the UserDetailsMap, not in the UserMap. Try:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User> {
    public UserMap() {
        Table("Users");
        Id(x => x.UserID);
        Map(x => x.UserName);
        Map(x => x.Password);
        HasOne(x => x.Details)
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389026/nhibernate-how-to-enable-lazy-loading-on-one-to-one-mapping) and [this](http://gnschenker.blogspot.com/2007/06/one-to-one-mapping-and-lazy-loading.html). It appears that you have to map the relationship as many-to-one from the User side and one-to-one constrained from the UserDetails side to get lazy loading working with one-to-one. I don't know if this is different in NH3.

Comment: Cheers but lazy loading is not supported if you don't specify constrained on a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: After further investigation.  It appears this solves the problem but lazy loading is still not working.  As soon as i grab the users it grabs the Details aswell.

Comment: Thanks again, i've tried mapping the User side using a many to one mapping (i've updated my original question with the new mapping).  But it's still not working.  I'd very much appreciate your help once more.  Thanks

Comment: Try changing the mapping to: References(x => x.Details);

Comment: That won't work since there's no DetailsID field in the Users table.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the way you are mapping the ID property is correct. shouldnt it just be an autoincremented id and your mapping should be as follows:

```
Id(x=>x.UserId);
```

I dont know the idea behind using Foreign and how it fits into things here.. can you please illustrate the logic behind that?

Comment: Cheers but the UserID field in the UsersDetails table is a reference to the Users table which contains the auto incrementing id.  Because it is a one-to-one mapping, the user id in the UsersDetails table is also the primary key.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have the foreign key identity mapping in your User mapping instead of the UserDetails and the native one in the UserDetails. I have been unable to find a reference for it, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've just found the following article (http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/01/08/composite-with-only-a-many-to-one-bad-idea.aspx) on the NHibernate Blog.  It's effectively what i wish to achieve but i still can't see how my mapping is any different.

Answer (score 0):

http://gorbach.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/fluent-onetoone/

```
HasOne(x => x.Details).Cascade.All().ForeignKey("UserDetails");
HasOne(x => x.User).Constrained();
var user = new User() { UserName = "Test", Password = "Test" };
user.Details = new UserDetails(user) { FirstName = "Test", LastName = "Test" };
user.Details.User = user;
session.Save(user);
```